# How to create a success message within a div upon successful form submission?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

The following form displays the success message every time on page launch in the browser logically but the form should display the success message only after it is submitted successfully.

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

$message = "Record has been updated successfully.";

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE table SET name=%s, email=%s, 

                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),

mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $test) or die(mysql_error()); 

$updateGoTo = "test.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

The html part of the form is as following:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
 <table align="center" class="test_table">
  <tr valign="baseline">
     <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="table-title">Name:</td>
     <td class="table-content"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_user['name'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr valign="baseline">
     <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="table-title">E-mail:</td>
     <td class="table-content"><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_user['email'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_user['id']; ?>" />
  <input class="submit" name="UpdateRecord" type="submit" id="UpdateRecord" value="Update Record" /></form>
```

This is how the success message is displayed within a div on the page:

```
<p> <?php 
  if (!empty($message)) {
  echo "<div class=\"successmessage\">" . $message . "</div>";
  } 
  ?></p>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this div on the same page as form?

Comment: Yes the success message div is on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created two function to show message

```
function addMessageStack($message,$type='success')
{
    $_SESSION['sess_MessageStack'][] =  array($type,$message);  
}
function showMessageStack()
{
    $str = '';
    if(count($_SESSION['sess_MessageStack']) > 0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['sess_MessageStack']);$i++)
        {
            $str.="<div class='".$_SESSION['sess_MessageStack'][$i][0]."Message left'>".$_SESSION['sess_MessageStack'][$i][1]."</div>";
        }
        unset($_SESSION['sess_MessageStack']);
        return $str;
    }   
}
```

In your example use like below

```
addMessageStack('Record has been updated successfully.');    
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
exit;
```

For dispaly message ,make sure there is session_start();

```
<?php echo showMessageStack(); ?>
```

It will display your message after form submit only

Comment: Well, I was unable to learn why an array should be created for a single message caused by a single form action? The suggested syntax  doesn't print any output on successful form submission. Moreover this way it's not possible to call and print the div anywhere on the page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it general function usefull to show multipal message at time , in your case remove array there is no issue and put the session_start() on top and put exit(); after redirect url i edit my answer

Comment: Now the success message is displayed after the form submission but it can't be displayed within a predefined and styled div as there is no option available to wrap the desired div with existing code. I tried to wrap the div `successmessage` with `showMessageStack();` in the following way `<?php echo "<div class=\"successmessage\">" .showMessageStack(). "</div>"; ?>` but the page always keep displaying the wrapped div though the success message is being displayed on that div properly after form submission. Thanks.

Comment: you can add your code by customize in showMessageStack() .. you can also addMessageStack('your message','error'); so it generate by it type like "error","info","success"

Answer (score 0):

hRaval, thanks a lot for your valued guideline from the very beginning and final hint.

The following addition to the addMessageStack solves the problem finally.

```
$message = "Record Has Been Updated Successfully";
addMessageStack("<div class=\"successmessage\">" . $message . "</div>");
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

It can be done more simply by storing the success message in a chosen variable or array or session after executing the query and counting the row without writing a lengthy function.

// Simplest method

```
mysql_select_db($database_test, $test); 
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $test) or die(mysql_error());
$Row_Count = mysql_num_rows($Result1);

if ($Row_Count > 0){
$successmessage = "Edited Successfully"; 
}
```

OR

// If you want to store all other success messages including this one in an array.

```
mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $test) or die(mysql_error());
$Row_Count = mysql_num_rows($Result1);

if ($Row_Count > 0){
$successmessage[] = "Edited Successfully"; 
}
```

OR

// If you want to define a header location after successful execution.

```
mysql_select_db($database_test, $test);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $test) or die(mysql_error());
$Row_Count = mysql_num_rows($Result1);

if ($Row_Count > 0){
$_SESSION['successmessage'] = "Edited Successfully"; 
}
```

Then in all the cases above you can call the success message anywhere in your document you want by checking if the variable is set or not empty. I'm giving an example below for the simplest method explained above.

```
if(isset($successmessage)){
echo "<div id=\"MyDesiredDiv\">" .$successmessage. "</div>";
}
```

OR

```
if(!empty($successmessage)){
echo "<div id=\"MyDesiredDiv\">" .$successmessage. "</div>";
}
```

> Important Note: MySql is deprecated long back. Try to use MySqli or
>   PDO and follow the above method.